# how to Add progress bar in tile container SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I want to add progress bar in tile container.I'm using the code from 
[SAPUI5 components](http://veui5infra:8080/demokit/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TileContainer/preview). this code works fine if i show simple tiles. but i want to add progress bar in my each tiles which will show percentage. How i can manipulate progress bar into tile container.

```
<TileContainer
  id="container"
  tileDelete="handleTileDelete"
  tiles="{/collectionStatus}">
  <StandardTile
    icon="sap-icon://{icon}"
  number="{count}"
    title = "{ parts : [{ path : 'ns'}]  , formatter : '.splitDataLakeNS' }"/>

</TileContainer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a progress bar to a sap.m.StandardTile component, because it does not accept aggregations, you can only customize it's properties.

Instead of StandardTile, you should use [CustomTile](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.CustomTile/samples), which allows you to display application specific content in the Tile control (a [ProgressIndicator](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.ProgressIndicator/samples) in your case).